# Django-nonrel sorting by foreignkey

Tags: sql-order-by, django-nonrel

Is there a way of returning items from a database in django-nonrel, using 'order_by' on a foreignkey?

Full details are as follows:

```
#Models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    article = models.TextField(help_text='Paste or type HTML in here')
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    ....

class TagItems(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    .... 

class TagRel(models.Model):
    the_post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    the_tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag')
```

TagRel defines a ManytoMany relationship between Post and TagItems classes.

I am wanting to get a list of articles for each tag.

```
#Desire output
My tag
-my first post
-my second post

My second tag
- my other post
- another post
```

All is good so far, as I use the following to filter the data:

```
def tagged_posts():
    tag_items = TagItems.objects.all()
    li =[]
    for item in tag_items:
        tag_rel_item = TagRel.objects.filter(the_tag__pk = item.pk)
        li.append(tag_rel_item)
    return {'list_of_objects': li}
```

I am using db-indexer to define the filter part of the query in db-indexes.py. All this works fine but I want to order my posts by publication dates.

Django docs tell me to use:

```
TagRel.objects.filter(the_tag__pk = item.pk).order_by('the_tag__pub_date')
```

But the order_by('the_tag__pub_date') part does not appear to be supported by django-nonrel.

The following also works in normal Django:

```
TagRel.objects.filter(the_tag__pk = item.pk).order_by('the_post')
```

This works because the Posts are already sorted by date in the model.

But this also does not appear to work in django-nonrel.

So my question is how do I return my posts ordered by date (latest>oldest)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same question too.  The workaround is the make a text field with the information, but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a guess at this - you're using a ManyToManyField.  I believe that's implemented using a ListProperty on App Engine's datastore.

See the section in the datastore documentation labeled "Properties With Multiple Values Can Have Surprising Behaviors": 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html

That's most likely why your results appear unsorted.  ManyToMany relations aren't supported natively in GAE.  You'd probably have to sort them yourself after you get the results back.